# Service bean without getters and setters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring mvc and I have a service class called UserManager. The class is used to manage a collection of users like add user and delete user from colection. Basicaaly it provides all the information about a collection of users.
This class is used by controllers to access user collection information.
Now the problem is I have to use it as a bean for spring injection. But a bean should have getters and setters only. 
So i am confused as to how i implement this class.

here is the code for UserManager

```
import com.bo.user.UserBO;

/*
 * UserManager class is a service class which provides service to Controller for managing the users in the system.
 * It has a collection _allUserMap which maintains the users inside the system all through the life of system.
 * It manages the addition, deletion and updation of users. 
 * UserBO is the service which helps UserManager access the users, individually, from Database 
 */
@Service
public class UserManager{
    @Autowired
    private UserBO userBo;
    private static Map<Integer,User> _allUserMap = new HashMap<Integer, User>();

    /*
     * Method populates the _allUserMap
     * using userBo
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void loadAllUsers(){
        Integer id = null;
        List<User> _allUserList = userBo.listAllUser();
        System.out.println("<--------Initializing all user map--------->");
        for(User user : _allUserList){
            id = user.getId();
            _allUserMap.put(id, user);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Adds the user after checking if the user exists
     * @param User:Takes the User to add from the Controller
     * @Return boolean User added or not
     * Beta 1.1 validation for correct user addition form input
     */
    public boolean addUser(User user){
        boolean userAdded = false;
        if (hasUser(user)){
            userAdded  = false;
        }else{
            userBo.save(user);
            userAdded = true;
        }
        return userAdded;
    }

    /*
     * Checks if the user is already present 
     * @Param User
     * @Return is user present 
     */
    private boolean hasUser(User formUser){
        boolean isUser = false;
        User user = null;
        for(Entry<Integer, User> entry: _allUserMap.entrySet()){
            user  = entry.getValue();
            if(user.equals(formUser)){
                isUser = true;
            }
            return isUser;
        }
        return isUser;
    }

    /*
     * @Param User
     * @Return String : message gives what feild is alreay in database
     */
    public String matchCredentails(User formUser){
        String message = "";
        User user = null;
        for(Entry<Integer, User> entry: _allUserMap.entrySet()){
            user  = entry.getValue();
            if(user.getEmail().equals(formUser.getEmail())){
                message = "Email alreay exists+";
            }
            if(user.getMobileNumber()== formUser.getMobileNumber()){
                message = message + "Mobile number alreay exists+";
            }

            if(user.getUserName().equals(formUser.getUserName())){
                message = message + "UserName alreay exists+";
            }
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

here is how i am accessing it in controller

```
 @Controller
public class UserController {   
    //These are the instances of the service providing bean and not the state of the spring controller
    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager;
```

My question is simple... should i make this class a bean. because this class is not a simple pojo by definition.

Comment: Start by posting your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is absolutely no need for getters and setters here since you are injecting the `UserBO` field through `@Autowired`.

The Spring documentation says

> A bean is simply an object that is instantiated, assembled and
>   otherwise managed by a Spring IoC container; other than that, there is
>   nothing special about a bean [...].

There is no mention of getters/setters and therefore you shouldn't think of them as necessary for *beans*. Use them when appropriate.

Comment: thanks for replying. but my question is ... should i make user manager a bean? since it has no getters and setters. I new to this. so please bear with me.

Comment: @vartika The fact that it is annotated with `@Service` and is managed by Spring already makes it a bean.

Comment: @vartika You're welcome. Different frameworks might give different meaning to terms. For example, a Java bean is a simple POJO, but a Spring bean is what I quoted. You just have to know what context you are working in.